# Is Rayo's number really that big?

Tags: big-numbers

I was reading about large numbers, and came across [Rayo's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayo's_number) which is defined to be the smallest integer that is not nameable by any expression in the language of set theory that contains less than $10^{100}$ symbols.

Now, my question is: Is this number really that large?

If we pick some "random" number $2091580284...384901284021$ with $10^{100}$ digits, wouldn't it be non-nameable with less than a googol symbols? Wouldn't this number be bigger or equal to Rayo's Number?

Comment: Lots of large numbers can be "named" quite efficiently.  $10^{10^{101}}$ for example.  The trick is to somehow characterize a large number without naming it.  The problem is that "characterize" sounds kind of like a synonym for "name", hence the interest in examples.

Comment: Suppose you took your example number manipulated it as follows:
$$2091580284\dots384901284021=2091580284\dots384901284020+1$$

$$=2(1045290142\dots192450642010)+1$$

$$=4(522645071\dots096225321005)+1$$

$$=20(1045290014\dots019245064201)+1$$

And so one, we factor.  If we hit a prime, or a number we can't easily factor, subtract out a part like I did in the first step, then continue on.  Eventually, you will hit a representation of the number using less than a googol of symbols.  Or I could ask if that number is larger than $P(P(P(\dots P(A)\dots)))$ for some set $A$.

Comment: You quoted the definition incorrectly. It is "The smallest number bigger than ..." so it is of course larger than 10^100 (which can be written with only a few symbols).

Comment: @Samuel yes, thats why I'm picking some "random" number that has not a simple representation such as 10^100

Comment: @Simple Art can this be done with every number?

Comment: @AndreiKh Well, the point of factoring it like so is that it can be done with any number, since we always take out a $"1"$ like in the first step, so we can always factor out another $2$.

Comment: @So it is just the binary representation of this number then? But then, one can find some number which has $10^100$ non-zero coefficients in its binary representation (i.e $111...1111_2$) or am I missing something?

Comment: @AndreiKh: With your definition you are indeed right. The number would be close to 10^100. But the definition on Wikipedia is different: it is the smallest number *bigger than every* number namable with a googol symbols, or equivalently, it is the largest number you can name with a googol symbols plus one. Thus it is larger than both 10^200 and Graham's number.

Comment: @Samuel Ahhhh, I got it! Thank you! Didn't gasp the definition correctly. Wow, now it's indeed large...

Comment: So as soon as we find Rayo's Number, it is no longer Rayo's Number because it is nameable with 13 characters (including punctuation and space).

Comment: @robjohn No, since the term "Rayo's number" is not an expression in first order logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As some of the comments already mentioned, you misquoted the definition. The correct definiton (quoting [Googology Wiki](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Rayo%27s_number)) is:

> the smallest positive integer bigger than any finite positive integer named by an expression in the language of first order set theory with a googol symbols or less

So while there are only approximately $(10^{100})^{(10^{100})}$ possible expressions, and only a very small fraction of them actually name a number, Rayo's number can be very large.

We don't exactly know how large, but there are good heuristic arguments that the busy beaver function $\Sigma$ can be implemented in a few million symbols. Given that $\Sigma$ grows much faster then $\mathrm{TREE}$ and all other computable functions, Rayo's number is much larger than  $(10^{100})^{(10^{100})}$ .

Comment: :0 A million symbols for $\text{BB}$... that's interesting.

Comment: Note for posterity: in 2020 it was shown the $2^{65536}-1$th [busy beaver number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) can be defined in 7901 symbols. (Emk, [A Rayo name larger than BB(10^100)](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Emk/A_Rayo_name_larger_than_BB(10%5E100)), Googology Wiki post)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Googology, I found a nice explanation of this.

[Explain Rayo please](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Superman37891/Explain_Rayo_please)

I will be using the outline of the comments to avoid plagiarizing, though you can read them as you please.

---

Let's start with a simple language, which I will call simple_arithmetic.

In simple_arithmetic, you can say numbers, and you can link them together using addition $+$, multiplication $\times$, and exponentiation $\wedge$ (each counts as one symbol).  Parenthesis are also usable (each one symbol).  We follow PEMDAS and `a^b^c=a^(b^c)`.

Likewise, the only number we have to start out with is $1$.  From there we can build any other number.

From the above, you will also note the only numbers constructable are natural numbers larger than or equal to $1$ (it counts as one symbol).  This is our entire set of numbers, and there can be no other numbers in simple_arithmetic.

There are no variables, no functions, etc.  A pretty basic language.

Now we can make $\operatorname{SA}(n)$, which equals the smallest number larger than any number nameable in $n$ symbols of simple_arithmetic.  So, let's start finding a few values:

$\operatorname{SA}(0)=1$, since I can't name any numbers yet, and $1$ is the smallest number in my language.

$\operatorname{SA}(1)=2$, since the only number you can make with one symbol is $1$, and $2$ is the smallest number larger than $1$.

$\operatorname{SA}(2)=2$ still, since we don't have enough operations to do anything, such as $1+1$.

$\operatorname{SA}(3)=3$, since we can now make $2=1+1$.

$\operatorname{SA}(4)=3$, not enough symbols to do much...

$\operatorname{SA}(5)=4$, since we can now make $3=1+1+1$.

$\operatorname{SA}(6)=4$

---

As you can probably tell, this is rather cumbersome, but there is eventually a small-ish jump.  For $n<7$, we have:

$\operatorname{SA}(2n-1)=n$

---

But then this pattern breaks.

$\operatorname{SA}(13)=9$, since $8=(1+1)\wedge(1+1+1)$

Indeed, one may note that for sufficiently large $n$, we have

$\operatorname{SA}(6n-1)\ge\underbrace{2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}}_n+1$, as it takes $6$ symbols to write $(1+1)\wedge$ and no $\wedge$ needed for the last exponent.

---

> Rayo's function is all the same, except the language it uses is way stronger.  Rayo's function is given by the smallest number larger than any number nameable in $n$ symbols of first order set theory, a language strong enough to allow variables, functions, recursion, etc.  Likely put, you can define stuff in this language you'd probably have a hard time explaining in English, and the results... are some very large, almost unexplainably large, numbers.

Comment: Even for this simple language, I think the situation is more complicated. For example, SA(13) = 10, because (1 + 1 + 1) ^ (1 + 1) is 9 and SA(15) is >=  28.

Comment: @cbmanica Meh, SA(15) couldn't be *too* big.... I hope.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just about how many digits it has, it's about the SYMBOLS you can express in.... so basically you can throw in something like Tree(tree(tree(tree..9...) ) ) With a total of one googol symbols. Keep in mind that merely tree(3) is immeasurably large. You cannot fathom hard large tree(tree(3) is, don't even talk about ~nonillions of trees nested within one another.

Comment: Actually, there are two tree sequences, the one you refer to being $TREE$, but $tree$ is much smaller than $TREE$.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. "Symbols" does not mean "function names", it means "symbols in the language of first-order set theory".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is in fact much bigger than what you named. The upper bound for something nameable in $10^{100}$ digits is $10^{10^{100}}$. Let $a_0=10^{10^{100}}$. Let $a_{n+1}=10^{10^{a_n}}$. Then this function can be defined inductively by $y=a_n\leftrightarrow y=10^{10^{100}}\lor \exists x(y=10^{10^{x}}\land \exists m(x=a_m\land m+1=n)$. Granted, I simplified this, and the full definition would probably include up to a $1000$ or more symbols, yet nowhere near $10^{100}$. As such, if we could name a number in $n$ or less symbols, then we can name name $a_n$ in $n=1000$ or less symbols, and so Rayo's number is much bigger then, say $a_{a_0}$, which is much bigger then $a_0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, a number like 10^(10^100) is much smaller than Rayo(10^100), because there are not a Googol digits, but a Googol symbols in first order set-theory, and it is pretty efficient to write down big numbers such as TREE(3), which can be expressed with MUCH LESS than a Googol symbols, you don't need anything like a Googol symbols to express TREE(3),and if we can say that :

```
              Rayo's Number > TREE(3)
```

We can certainly say that :

```
              Rayo's Number > Any number with 10^100 digits
```

So Rayo's Number is really that big.