# What is explanation of $\text{Sat}([φ],s)$ in the definition of Rayo’s number?

Tags: logic, set-theory, big-numbers

The definition of $\text{Sat}([φ],s)$ can be found [here](http://web.mit.edu/arayo/www/bignums.html).

All I want is an explanation of what each line in this definition means and how $\text{Sat}([φ],s)$ works. The only relevant thing that I have found is the following comment ( [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199190/the-first-few-values-of-rayos-function#comment4994464_2236031) ):

> He is referring to truth in the set-theoretic universe (not the natural numbers), and the class R is a truth function, for the clauses in the definition assert that R obeys the Tarskian recursion, and the final clause asserts that phi is true of s, according to the truth predicate R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the satisfaction predicate. It takes a formula and an assignment to the variables of the formula, and tells you whether or not the statement is true or false.

Rayo's number is really just a complicated way of saying that it is the smallest number which larger than all those numbers definable *in the set theoretic universe* with a formula of at most googol symbols.

The catch, of course, is that almost always we talk about the natural numbers as their own entity, so naming large numbers is taken by talking about some function like $\rm TREE$, or Busy Beaver, or so on. But the mathematical universe is so much larger. The set theoretic universe gives us tools much larger than just the natural numbers.

It also opens the door to the ills of independence, at least when playing this game of naming the largest number (e.g. $n$ is the least integer such that $2^{\aleph_n}>\aleph_{n+1}$, or $0$ otherwise). Which is why we need to refer to a fixed universe, and to the satisfaction relation *of that universe*.

Comment: Regarding the quote “Which is why we need to refer to a fixed universe, and to the satisfaction relation _of that universe_” — does the definition imply that we are allowed to choose _any_ universe? If no, then why doesn’t the definition explicitly state what set-theoretic universe should be chosen? And what is the meaning of each of the following three lines? 1) ``([ψ] = `x_i ∈ x_j' ∧ t(x_1) ∈ t(x_j))``; 2) ``([ψ] = `(θ∧ξ)' ∧ R([θ],t) ∧ R([ξ],t))``; 3) ``([ψ] = `∃x_i (&theta)' and, for some an x_i-variant t' of t, R([θ],t'))``

Comment: No, the definition is always with respect to a single universe which is implicitly prefixed. Which might as well be the mathematical universe, as a whole, if you take set theoretic foundations of mathematics along for a ride.

Comment: The three lines you define literally state the definition of truth in the set theoretic universe. Do you know Tarski's definition of the truth in a structure?

Comment: I have read Tarski's Truth Definitions [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/), but haven't seen any definition that resembles the definition of $\text{Sat}$. Is it possible to translate these three lines to a more readable text? And where can I read more about the definition of truth in the set theoretic universe?

Comment: Well. The definition of truth start with atomic formulas—in the set theoretic context that is just $x=y$ or $x\in y$—and proceeds to connectives like $\land$ and negation, and finally quantifiers. That's all that there is to those three lines. And the truth definition in the set theoretic universe is no different. The set theoretic universe, after all, is just a structure, whose truth is given by the same Tarskian definition.

Comment: It seems to me that I can imagine the meaning of all lines, but I still cannot obtain the meaning of ``([ψ] = `∃x_i (&theta)' and, for some an x_i-variant t' of t, R([θ],t'))``

Comment: Do you know what it means that $M\models_t\exists x\theta(x)$?

Comment: In this formula, I am not sure I understand the meaning of subscript $t$. Also, I am not sure I can understand the meaning of $\theta(x)$.

Comment: The meaning is that $t$ is an assignment, and $\theta(x)$ is a formula whose free variable is $x$ (if it even has a free variable). Perhaps it would be a good choice to start with learning about predicate logic and first-order logic *before* trying to jump as far as the truth in the set theoretic universe and the satisfaction predicate.

Comment: I knew that $\phi(x)$ might imply a formula whose free variable is $x$, but then what does `∃x_i (&theta)` mean?

Comment: It is a formula that has the form $\exists x_i\theta$, where $x_i$ is the $i$th free variable in the language (because the language has infinitely many free variables). And $\theta$ is some other formula.

Comment: The last claification: can I read the excerpt `for some an x_i-variant t' of t` as [for some $x_i$-variant $t'$ of $t$]?

Comment: It means that you take $t$, and only change its assign of $x_i$. In other words, $\exists x\theta$ is true if and only if there is some object $a$ such that when assigned $x$ with $a$, $\theta$ is true.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, I am interested what is the meaning of the formula $M \models_t \exists x \theta(x)$. If $t$ is a variable assignment, then...?

Comment: I think that [it is the smallest number which is not definable in the set theoretic universe with a formula of at most googol symbols] in the current answer should be edited to [it is the smallest number bigger than every finite number $N_i$, assuming that $N_i$ is definable in the set theoretic universe with a formula of at most googol symbols]. The difference is very important.

Comment: @lyricallywicked: I don't understand your comment. What is the distinction?

Comment: 1/2: Maybe I am wrong, but here's how I understand it. Assuming that the set-theoretic universe is fixed and $y \le 10^{100}$, let $X = \{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{i-1}, X_i\}$ denote a finite set of all numbers that are definable by some formula of $y$ symbols. Then let $T = \{T_1, T_2, T_3, \ldots\}$ denote an infinite set of all numbers that are not definable (in the same set-theoretic universe) by any formula of $y$ symbols.

Comment: 2/2: Then consider a finite set $Y = \{0, 1, \ldots, X_i-2, X_i-1\}$. It will contain unimaginably many elements that intersect with $T$. All these numbers are less than $X_i$, so they should be ignored. This is why Rayo's number $N$ was defined as $N = X_i + 1$, not as $N = T_1$.

Comment: Perhaps for future reference, but here's a simpler way to make the same point: "the smallest number not in $\{0,5,42\}$ is not the same as the least number larger than all members of $\{0,5,42\}$".